# E6 Ajax request not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, ecmascript-6

I have a script where I want to fetch some json data from an endpoint, but I get an error, this is my script:

```
function httpGet(url) {
    return new Promise(
        function (resolve, reject) {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    // Success
                    resolve(this.response);
                } else {
                    // Something went wrong (404 etc.)
                    reject(new Error(this.statusText));
                }
            }
            request.onerror = function () {
                reject(new Error(
                    'XMLHttpRequest Error: '+this.statusText));
            };
            request.open('GET', url);
            request.send();
        });
}

var url = 'https://api.jsonPlaceholder.com';

httpGet(url)
  .then(JSON.parse)
  .then((r) => {
    console.log(r);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Then, in the console it throws an error:

> Error
>       at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (app.js:11)
>       at app.js:18
>       at Promise ()
>       at httpGet (app.js:2)
>       at app.js:25

Comment: Just curious... Why don't you use the [`Fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)?

Comment: @Andreas: Probably wants to support IE?

Comment: Seems to run fine for me other than the api url is bad. What browser are you using?

Comment: wasn't even aware of it? will definitely try it now!

Comment: @Leff Don't forget the [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) too, if required

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [Promises](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises) and IE? Edge knows [Promises and Fetch](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch)

Comment: @Andreas: OP's using some ES2015 features, probably transpiling and including a Promise polyfill. Of course, he/she could include a `fetch` polyfill too... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just check `status`, you have to check for `readyState == 4` before you can decide what happened:

```
function httpGet(url) {
    return new Promise(
        function (resolve, reject) {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState === 4) {                            // ***
                    if (this.status === 200) { 
                        // Success
                        resolve(this.response);
                    } else {
                        // Something went wrong (404 etc.)
                        reject(new Error(this.statusText));
                    }
                }                                                       // ***
            }
            request.onerror = function () {
                reject(new Error(
                    'XMLHttpRequest Error: '+this.statusText));
            };
            request.open('GET', url);
            request.send();
        });
}
```

[The spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-response-attribute) says accessing `this.response` before the request is complete should just return an empty string, but for me using Chrome v57, doing so gives the error you quoted. Adding the `readyState` check fixes it.

Comment: This wouldn't throw an error though, would it? Wouldn't it just trigger the Promises `catch` early?

Comment: @CodingIntrigue: 'tis a good point, it jumped out at me so much I didn't remember to think about the quoted error. So I wondered if `this.response` was throwing, but [the spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-response-attribute) doesn't say it should if you access it too early. Edit: Ah, Chrome is throwing despite the spec...

Comment: this works now, I can fetch the data, with your code

Comment: If this works, then I guess it wasn't a thrown error after all - just log output

Comment: @CodingIntrigue: Chrome throws an error when you access `this.response` before the request is complete, despite the spec. Just replicated it locally, exact error the OP quoted. Very surprising.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Interesting - I did not know that! Thanks :)